# Use python code in .net webform

Tags: python, asp.net, python-imaging-library, ironpython

i have a script for reducing image size in python

i have a website which is on .net

my python code is

```
import os
from PIL import Image    
for file in os.listdir('sample/tp'):
    image_size=(os.stat("sample/tp/"+file).st_size) #size in bytes
    foo=Image.open("sample/tp/"+file)
    max_size=250000

    if image_size > max_size:
        foo.save("sample/tp/"+file,quality=int((max_size*100)/image_size))
```

in .net I have tried using *ironpython* but as i require to import the PIL library it wont work.

Thankyou

Comment: There are certainly some equivalent libs for .net...

Comment: I didn't got any with import python libraries support, can you suggest please @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: What I meant is that there are certainly some .net lib for image manipulation - no need for Python here. Googling for ".net image resize" should get you started...

Comment: Have you tried pythonnet?